# Как обновить массив в родительском scope при открытом модальном окне (Angular UI Bootstrap Modal)?

Tags: массивы, javascript, angularjs

Всем доброго времени суток.

Столкнулся с одной проблемой после рефакторинга кода бэкенда к приложению Системы тестирования. Тест представляет собой список вопросов с несколькими вариантами ответов, при этом один и только один вариант ответа является верным.

После дебага все работало нормально, но вся логика по управлению вопросами и ответами была расположена в одном контроллере. Я перенес логику ответов в отдельный вложенный контроллер, и после этого возникла проблема. Перепробовал много различных способов, пока безрезультатно.

По дизайну добавление и редактирование вопросов и ответов происходит в модальном окне ([Angular UI Boostrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) Modal). Шаблон расположен отдельно и не повторяется при вставке каждого вопроса и ответа. Когда данные с формы не валидны, показываются ошибки валидации, в противном случае показывается сообщение об успешном сохранении, и все поля формы сбрасываются в свое начальное состояние. Все это происходит при открытом модальном окне, закрыть его можно только по нажатию кнопки "Отмена", крестика или Esc.

Мне нужно обновить $scope.questions в QuestionsCtrl из модального окна (кнопка добавления также находится внутри модального окна). После однократного нажатия кнопки данные обновляются, однако сообщение об успехе или ошибки валидации не показываются, и поля формы не возвращаются в первоначальное состояние. Повторные клики больше не вызывают функцию, т.е. она выполняется только один раз.

Без модального окна, но со вложенными контроллерами все работает, как и хотелось.

Есть вариант использовать promise result, но для него обязательно закрывать модальное окно, тут же сама идея такова, что менеджер может добавить сколько угодно вопросов и ответов без переоткрывания окна.

Пробовал также [Angular Strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/), результат тот же.

Важный момент - с каждым запросом на добавление / редактирование в модальном окне шлется актуальный список вопросов и ответов в json, после чего происходит полное переприсвоение $scope.questions. Может это не лучший вариант, но так делалось для того, чтобы менеджеры всегда работали только с актуальной информацией (случаи одновременного редактирования одного теста), а также для редактирования в разных вкладках и браузерах одним человеком (это уже гораздо менее вероятно, но тем не менее, может привести к коллизиям).

Проблемное место было выявлено - оно кроется как раз в обновлении $scope.questions.
Обновление происходит путем полного переприсвоения, если добавлять новые элементы просто через push, проблем нет.
Проход по массиву, пришедшему с сервера со сравнением и удалением / добавлением новых элементов в зависимости от изменений - на мой взгляд, плохая идея.
Но даже если не переприсваивая, удалить все элементы из массива и потом последовательно в цикле добавить новые, проблема остается.
Если говорить более конкретно, как только массив становится пустым, то и возникает данная ошибка.

Я создал [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/mLTOd0WwBhlYsUMXW16V), оставил только самое необходимое для лучшего понимания проблемы.

Собственно вопрос, как при открытом модальном окне, при нажатии кнопочки "Добавить" корректно в фоне обновлять массив $scope.questions?

Comment: если честно многобукф. вот это надо ?

http://plnkr.co/edit/GHVCKyy9To4BzjMbNx9q?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А, я все понял про вашу проблему, в общем нельзя вам переписывать questions, по крайней мере таким образом, т.к. вы просто удаляете ссылку на scope с modal в результате, если хотите всё-же чтобы работало, изолируйте `$scope`.

[как-то так](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qv8fHeH3LgOmXXYebgGq?p=preview)

Comment: Спасибо, такой способ действительно работает. Считается ли это плохой практикой? Нужно ли вручную где-то вызывать $destroy для данного scope? Или в этом нет необходимости, т.к. он единожды создастся? Вынесите ваш комментарий в ответ, т.к. это работающее решение.

Comment: насчет плохой практики не уверен, посмотрите дебагером ангуляр когда этот scope пропадает, мне больше кажется неправильным, что у вас этот modal в контроллере answers, что он там делает если он меняет и questions тоже ?
разве [так](http://plnkr.co/edit/t892f8KUhPMzE5K0BfQ7?p=preview) не логичнее ?(и проблема исчезает сама собой)

Comment: Т.е. логичнее все же будет оставить всю логику в одном контроллере (QuestionsCtrl)? Или может быть имеет смысл через factory questions обновлять? Я кстати пробовал, добавлял watch на изменение, и тоже при обновлении была такая ошибка.

Comment: ну как, логику для ответов в этом контроллере, для конкретных вопросов в answerCtrl,для всех ответов в вопросе answersCtrl  а для конкретных ответов в questionCtrl

понятно что все контроллеры вам не понадобятся.

Comment: Запутался, если честно... Вообще идея была такая, что при каждом ajax запросе происходит обновление $scope.questions. Сам ajax вызывается через сервис, в контроллере через watch отслеживается момент успешного завершения запроса и совершаются некие общие действия, в частности обновление $scope.questions (чтобы избежать дублирования кода). Все это было по большей части расположено в одном контроллере (помимо modalInstance модального окна), в какой-то момент код стал разрастаться, и я начал переделывать на отдельные контроллеры.

Comment: мне кажется watch - лишнее, но я щас не скажу, просплюсь, посмотрю еще раз. вы сделайте на plunker пример с вашим ajax запросом.